# Extrusion pulling the whole mesh

Tags: mesh

I've created a cube mesh. I've changed its dimensions and from the top face of the mesh, I've extruded. However, whenever I move the top face of the extrusion, it pulls the whole object and not just the extrusion I made like it has with other objects I've extruded from. Why is it acting differently?

Nvm, found out. Disabled soft-selection that I must have enabled by accident.